# Howto create tags in C/C++ program

Tags: c++, c, ctags

I want to know what is the best tags system for a c/c++ or java project.

I have read about ctags, exhuberant ctgas, cscope gnu global (gtags), but don't know what is the difference between them.

I'm using Windows 7, and Notepad++ or maybe moving to SublimeText (because it is crossplatform and seems to be quite powerful).

Could you give me any hint on the difference between these tags systems? Any help is really appreciated.

TA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could you give me any hint on the difference between these tags systems?

These three tools pretty much try to do the same thing. They all try to create tag information from source code.

From what I recall ctags was the original Unix based tag tool, exhuberant ctags was created in an attempt to build a better ctags and cscope is more of a project based tagging tool.

I myself use the Windows based Zeus editor and it uses the exhuberant ctags.

Most Windows based editor tend to use the exhuberant ctags where ase most Unix/Linux based editors like Vim, EMACS tend to use ctags.